# Unable to import opencv3 module using android studio 2021.3.1 arctic fox

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, module

In the old version of android studio as 4.2 I could import a new module like opencv without problems, however in this new version of android studio called 2021.3.1 arctic fox I'm unable to import the sdk folder or java from opencv librarie.

Steps:
I went to File->Import new module:

[image]

Then I chose the java folder inside sdk from opencv:

[image]

As we can see I'm unable of press the next button. I tried chaguing the module name but was useless.

In my gradle file I added `applicationId "opencv.org"` and I added the dependency: `testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'`

Also I tried chaguing:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'

}
```

to

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'

}
```

All this doesn't work, any Idea will be great to fix this in this new version of android studio. Thanks.

Comment: here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/68738767/5773037

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV Android Studio module importing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68649524/opencv-android-studio-module-importing-issue)